# How to add custom variable and its related value into protractor-html-screenshot-reporter metadata

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

There is a req of adding one header field and one corresponding value underneath it in the html report generated by using **protractor-html-screenshot-reporter** plugin.

I tried  exploring it and found that the html page generated is already created into **jsonparser.js** file of this plugin and in-fact the data is also being added to this html table created.

I tried one solution like adding the below mentioned lines in conf file

```
metadataBuilder: function metaDataBuilder(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities) {
        return {value: results.passed()};
   }
```

but this does not work for me.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea..